# using static methods with properties

Tags: c#, methods, properties, static

I found out about properties a couple of days ago(not sure if I understood how to use them very well). So I decided to make some tests.
so here's what Ive done :
I created a class  that contains some properties such as :

```
public string _string1 { get; set; }
public string _string2 { get; set; }
```

and then I created a method in the same class lets say like this :

```
public static string  Example()
{
   switch(_string1.length > _string2.length)
   {
      case true :
             return _string1;
             break;
      default : return _string2;
   }
}
```

just a stupid example to understand a bit
and then I called the method from the main class after that I got a couple of errors :
An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'xxx.properties._string1.get'

Well its certainly a stupid mistake but I'm new to c# and I could use some assistance.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to make your properties static too:

```
public static string _string1 { get; set; }
public static string _string2 { get; set; }
```

Essentially a static method has no state. Those fields when declared in a non-static manner are essentially like a state, therefore it can't access them. By marking them static you say this is the Global value for the AppDomain.

One thing to be wary of using static fields like this however is if you start using any sort of threading and try to store state then you can end up with nasty issues to debug because you've no idea what state you're shared resources are in.

A way to protect against this (if you don't need state) is to define these as constants fields instead. Then you can't modify them, but means you need not worry about someone changing them when you didn't expect it.

```
public const string _string1;
public const string _string2;
```

Comment: Small type: properties, not fields.

Comment: @oleksii: I've updated to reflect that - although not all people may be aware of what an AppDomain is if they don't understand statics.

Comment: @user3210018: Great - if it helps and there aren't any better answers please feel free to accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

A static method can always access other static members only. Now since your properties are not static hence your static method cannot access/manipulate them.

You can make these fields as static and then the error will go away. Once these are static no object reference would be required to access them.
They can then be simply accessed through the classname itself.

for example

```
public class YourClass
{
  public static string _string1 { get; set; }
  public static string _string2 { get; set; } 

  public static string  Example()
  {
    switch(_string1.length > _string2.length)
    {
     case true :
         return _string1;
         break;
     default : return _string2;
    }
  }
}
```

Now in your program:

```
YourClass._string1="some string";  // You can access the static properties with class name
YourClass._string2="some other string";

YourClass.Example() // You can call the static function with class name.
```

Answer (score 1):

It's all about instance versus static scope. Whilst the examples above make your error go away, it is important to understand when to use static methods, variables, properties versus instance ones. In fact, you could say that using static members is not really a pure OOP practice. Most of the time, static members are misused because people misunderstand these OOP basics.

Static methods and variables are shared amongst all object instances for your class. Therefore, in most scenarios, you will need to have a specific requirement to have a static method/variable, such as keeping a total count of objects in a static variable which would be accessible across all your object instances.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new instance of the class where variables are.

```
public class YourClass
{
   public string _string1 { get; set; }
   public string _string2 { get; set; } 
   ...
}

public static string  Example()
{
   YourClass yourClass = new YourClass();
   switch(_string1.length > _string2.length)
   {
      case true :
             return yourClass._string1;
             break;
      default : return yourClass._string2;
   }
}
```